# Configuracion dns LAN y WAN

Tags: dns

Estoy montando un servidor OpenVZ con varias máquinas dns, web, mail... etc

Tengo más de una máquina para servicio web y he configurado los DNS con los registros de dominio en cada máquina.

La red local interna me funciona correctamente y traduce los dominios a cada máquina pero no consigo "conectar" desde internet con la máquina correspondiente a un dominio determinado.

Parece que hay una solución con un router con dns ( tipo cisco).

Pero puede haber más soluciones ?

Gracias

Comment: esos "dominios" son reales y estan registrados y apuntan a la ip publica de tus maquinas? si no es asi, desde internet no vas a poder conectar a esas maquinas por el dominio...

Comment: Por supuesto. Todos se dirigen a la IP pública. El problema parece ser que el router no consulta los DNS de la LAN interna.

Comment: En principio la resolución de nombres del router debería ser primero tu DNS interno y luego uno externo. Lo tienes configurado así?

Comment: El router no me acepta un DNS interno ¿?
Claro que debería se así, pero no lo es.
Solo puedo seleccionar una zona DMZ.
Pero me parece, por lo que he visto, que estás dando en el clavo.

Comment: Si no te admite un segundo DNS, quizás el campo de DNS puedas poner varios seguidos, separados por espacios o por comas. Algo como `192.168.1.10, 8.8.8.8` o `192.168.1.10 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Resulta que el router, de vodafone, venía configurado como DHCP para tomar la IP pública desde la compañía, con sus DNSs fijos.
En cuanto lo he cambiado a IP estática y pongo mi IP pública, me permite configurar el Gateway y los DNS que yo quiera.
Casi seguro que ahora todo se puede configurar correctamente. Ahora ya es cosa mía. 
Muchas GRACIAS ! por tu aportación. Has encendido la mecha de la solución.
Saludos

No sé si esto debería de ponerse como respuesta final. SOLUCIONADO